# Microsoft Exchange, which alternatives?

Tags: windows, email, exchange, open-source

is there anyone who knows (or has had experience) with alternatives to Microsoft Exchange?

I'm looking for a solution more cheaper (or free) that can be installed on Windows servers.

Ideally, an open source mail servers that also exposes Services/API to interface by code, in order to develop appropriate software for querying mail and loading contacts.

Can you tell me some product to view?

Thank you in advance for any useful information about.

Comment: "Product […] recommendations are off-topic because they attract low quality, opinionated and spam answers, and the answers become obsolete quickly."

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft exchange is not very expensive. Whatever you think you will be saving in cost will be offset by the amount of time necessary to implement the solution.